# Decoding a 16 bit one channel png in c# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compression, png, decode

I've been stuck for a week trying to decode a 16-bit 1 channel png in Unity. The image is in form of a byte array that needs to be decoded to access the individual pixel values. The image is a depth image where each pixel contains a depth measure.

I can't use Unity's Texture2d.loadImage(), since it automatically changes the format to RGBA24 for some reason. I also looked at the opencv plugin, but it is non-free and is therefore not an option. I can neither use System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapDecoder from the .NET framework since **my platform is Ubuntu**.

I do not have a .NET ide, I use MonoDevelop through Unity.

Hope you guys can help! :)

Comment: You might try with https://github.com/leonbloy/pngcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the png images had 12 bytes of garbage that I had to remove before they could be removed. Texture2d.loadImage() worked after this was done. The image in question came from ROS as a CompressedImage message through ROSBridgeLib in Unity. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick to convert the image from PNG to PGM and go from there.  PGM is easy to work with, containing just a simple header with "P2 width height maxval" followed by the pixels in top-left to bottom-right order:

```
# Make a 4x4 test image with 16-bit grayscale pixels
im7q16magick gradient:[4x4] -depth 16 g16.png

# Convert it to PGM format
im7q16magick g16.png -compress none g16.pgm

# Print it out
cat g16.pgm

P2
4 4
65535
65535 65535 65535 65535 
49151 49151 49151 49151 
32768 32768 32768 32768 
16384 16384 16384 16384
```